# Problemas al actualizar version principal de base de datos RDS MariaDB 10.11

Tags: base-de-datos, mariadb, amazon-rds

Tengo una instancia RDS en AWS, la instancia esta utilizando el motor de base de datos MariaDB con la versión 10.6.15 y al queres actualizar a la versión 10.11.4 (ó 10.11.5) me arroja el siguiente error:

> Lo sentimos, pero se produjo un error en su solicitud para modificar la instancia de base de datos dbprueba.
> The AllowMajorVersionUpgrade flag must be present when upgrading to a new major version

No estoy pudiendo resolver el problema para poder aplicar dicha actualización, no encuentro la opción para AllowMajorVersionUpgrade.

Probe cambiar el tipo de instancia pero no resolvio el problema.